# ¿Que significa "cuartodías"?

Tags: vocabulario, significado, tiempo, neologismos, literatura

Sé que hace referencia a un intervalo de tiempo o a una fecha pero no sé cual exactamente. Ejemplo:

> Tras dos cuartodías de camino...
>
> Se había alojado en la posada durante dos cuartodías...
>
> ... estará tan a salvo conmigo como en los dos últimos cuartodías en que te he acompañado a tu casa.

- [*Magia robada*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=eMCmCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT603&lpg=PT603&dq=cuartod%C3%ADas), Trudi Canavan

Comment: Por lo que he encontrado esa cita pertenece al libro "Magia robada" de Trudi Canavan, un libro de magia y fantasía. Es muy, muy probable que la autora haya inventado esa palabra, con lo cual poco podemos apuntar los que no hayamos leído el libro. Creo que este no es el sitio adecuado para esa pregunta. Puedes intentarlo aquí https://scifi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RubioRic es usado en otros libros(de la misma autora) pero no hay ninguna referencia de su significado (no hay en el glossario del libro mucho menos en la historia) tb es usado "primerdías" (en ingles encontre como "Firstday") ejemplo "Quiero que cenes conmigo aquí cada primerdía por la noche". no creo que es del genero fantasia (tengo el custumbre de leer e nunca he visto esa palabra en ese contexto).considerare que es una palabra unica que la autora usa, dejare uns dias abierto(si alguien conozca)

Comment: No entiendo tu aclaración. No pretendía decir que esa palabra fuera común en el género fantástico. En ese sitio aclaran dudas relacionadas con esa temática pero puedes preguntar por un libro o un autor específico, como en este caso.

Comment: creo que me equivoque, tentare hacer alguna pregunta en ese sitio,(no sabia que hacia referencia a autores tambien)

Comment: Podría ser una mala traducción/adaptación de **fortnight** El libro se llama **Thief's Magic** en su version original en inglés o sea que la palabra esa se la inventó el traductor.
*A fortnight is a unit of time equal to 14 days (2 weeks). The word derives from the Old English term fēowertyne niht, meaning "fourteen nights".*

Comment: Relacionado: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26016/what-is-a-jupia

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### *cuartodía* = el cuarto día

En [la versión original](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Gb8eAgAAQBAJ&q=quarterday) de la novela (inglés), se emplea el término "quarterday":

> ... but at this time on a quarterday, between the morning lessons and worship and the afternoon market... And as the fourth set of four days - the end of a halfseason - it was a day the more pious of the city's citizens spent at home fasting and praying.

> Four quarterdays later - a full halfseason...

> "A few more days."
>
> Another two quarterdays passed before he returned.

Dado los contextos, y que también usa los términos reales "day", "week", "month", postulo que significa:

1. el cuarto (o octavo) día de la semana, c.f:

   - *semana < septimāna* "séptimo"
   - *[huit jours](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/huit_jours)* - "semana"
   - *quinze jours* - "quincena"
2. (por extensión) un período de cuatro días

---

## Tiempo en la novela

Parece que la sociedad de la novela construye su concepto de tiempo alredador de períodos de cuatro días, y que hay dos 'días sagradas' por semana:

- 4 días = 1 cuartodía
- 2 cuartodías = 1 semana
- 4 cuartodías = 1 mediotemporada
- 4 semanas = 1 temporada

Comment: +1 Por el esfuerzo de buscarlo en el original, cosa que también hice ayer en el mismo Google Books sin llegar a conclusión clara alguna. Aún así insisto en que el sitio sobre ciencia-ficción y fantasía es el más adecuado para esta casuística concreta.

Comment: In some English speaking countries a quarter day is one of the four days on which rent is due: Lady Day (March 25), Midsummer, Michaelmas (29 September) and Christmas Day. I had initially assumed that was meant here but it clearly is as you say.

Answer (score 2):

Teoría:

La autora mencionada es australiana y el libro (Thief's Magic) mencionado fue escrito originalmente en inglés por lo que la palabra *cuartodia* se la inventó un traductor.

Existe un término muy empleado en la literatura en inglés especialmente en ese género que es **fortnight**

> A fortnight is a unit of time equal to 14 days (2 weeks). The word derives from the Old English term fēowertyne niht, meaning "fourteen nights"

No he podido encontrar ningún acceso al libro original en inglés pero esa sería la única forma de comprobar la teoría de que *fortnight* fue traducido erróneamente como *cuartodia*.

Comment: [La versión original](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Gb8eAgAAQBAJ&q=quarterday) usa la palabra inventada "quarterday". Parece razonable que es una alusión entre *quarter/day ~ fourth/night ~ fort/night.*

Comment: Excelente @ukemi. La version en inglés era la clave. Gracias.